# c# Regex of value after certain words

Tags: c#, regex

I have a question at regex I have a string that looks like:

> Slot:0 Module:No module in slot

And what I need is a regex that well get values after slot and module, slot will allways be a number but i have a problem with module (this can be word with spaces), I tried:

```
 var pattern = "(?<=:)[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
 foreach (string config in backplaneConfig)
 {
     List<string> values = Regex.Matches(config, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
     modulesInfo.Add(new ModuleIdentyfication { ModuleSlot = Convert.ToInt32(values.First()), ModuleType = values.Last() });
 }
```

So slot part works, but module works only if it is a word with no spaces, in my example it will give me only "No". Is there a way to do that

Comment: `@"Slot:(\d+)\s*Module:(.+)"` and grab Group 1 and 2. You may use it with `Regex.Match`

Comment: Or perhaps  `(?<=:)(?:\d+\b|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)` https://regex101.com/r/XCTaFE/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex to *capture* the necessary details in the input string:

```
var pattern = @"Slot:(\d+)\s*Module:(.+)";
foreach (string config in backplaneConfig)
{
    var values = Regex.Match(config, pattern);
    if (values.Success)
    {
        modulesInfo.Add(new ModuleIdentyfication { ModuleSlot = Convert.ToInt32(values.Groups[1].Value), ModuleType = values.Groups[2].Value });
    }
 }
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Slot%3A%28%5Cd%2B%29%5Cs*Module%3A%28.%2B%29&i=Slot%3A0%20Module%3ANo%20module%20in%20slot). Group 1 is the `ModuleSlot` and Group 2 is the `ModuleType`.

**Details**

- `Slot:` - literal text
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `Module:` - literal text
- `(.+)` -  Capturing group 2: the rest of the string to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be to add 'space' to your pattern

```
var pattern = "(?<=:)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+";
```

But the best solution would probably the answer from @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to match either 1+ digits followed by a word boundary or match a repeating pattern using your character class but starting with `[a-zA-Z]`

```
(?<=:)(?:\d+\b|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)
```

- `(?<=:)` Assert a `:` on the left
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+\b` Match 1+ digits followed by a word boundary
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` Start a match with a-zA-Z
  - `(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat a space and what is listed in the character class
- `)` Close on capturing group

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3a%29%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5cb%7c%5ba-zA-Z%5d%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d*%28%3f%3a+%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b%29*%29&i=Slot%3a0+Module%3aNo+module+in+slot)

Answer (score 0):

Plase replace this:

```
 // regular exp.
(\d+)\s*(.+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for such simple parsing. Try below:

```
var str = "Slot:0 Module:No module in slot";
str.Split(new string[] { "Slot:", "Module:"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(s => s.Trim());
```